# помогите настроить base url для всех routes Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Всем привет!
Тренируюсь с Angular, настроил ui-router все было хорошо, радовался сему творению. Но мне не нравилось это:

```
/#/
```

Погуглив решил вопрос и теперь у меня все как нужно и вместо `/#/` на `/`.

Но после, столкнулся с проблемой, как только обновить страницу сразу же выдает ошибку 404, как будто неправильные пути.

Сам сайт - http://lost-found-ua.esy.es/

это `/#/` на это `/` решил так:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
<head>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашел - нужно в файл `.htaccess` добавить этот код:

```
RewriteEngine On  
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
  RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете выложить Ваш полный фал .htaccess. Перепробовал уже кучу вариантов, все равно, при перезагрузки на любом из стейтов, кроме "/", выдает ошибку 500 Internal Server Error. Может это проблема в сервере ? делаю на локалке на ОпенСервер

Comment: Если этот топик не решает вашу задачу, задайте  новый вопрос и сошлитесь на текущий как на взаимосвязанный.